# splitter in pyside ui now visible

Tags: python, pyside

why is the splitter not displaying in the tab?

I'm not entirely sure what is wrong. I'm guessing that the layout box is not resizing to match the size of the tab, in return is producing such a small window in the tab which isn't big enough to display it's contents. Any code suggestions are welcome.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        # controls - main
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        main_tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget()

        # controls - factions tab
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        factions_tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        factions_tab_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        topleft = QtGui.QFrame(factions_tab)
        topleft.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)

        topright = QtGui.QFrame(factions_tab)
        topright.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)

        splitter1 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
        splitter1.addWidget(topright)

        factions_tab_layout.addWidget(splitter1)
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))

        main_tabWidget.addTab(factions_tab, "Factions")

        # main layout
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(main_tabWidget)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.center()
        self.show()

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def onChanged(self, text): 
        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()        


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `factions_tab_layout` is never given a parent, and is not set as a layout on any widget. This means its child widgets will be garbage-collected when `initUI` returns, because you do not give any of them parents, either.

Minimal fix:

```
    factions_tab_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(factions_tab)
```

Comment: what would be your recommended fix to avoid the garbage collection issues

Comment: more importantly you wrote 'minimal fix' what would be your recommended ideal fix.

Comment: @JokerMartini. My preference is to always explicitly set a parent, even if I know Qt will implicitly re-parent (which is what normally happens with layouts). The main practical benefit of parenting is that it makes it easy for Qt to delete things properly (because it can recursively delete all children as well). It also guarantees that you can navigate through the object hierarchy using `parent()`. But, personally, I just like not having to remember whether a parent is needed or not. Explicit is better than implicit ;-)